# How can I set class="active" to navigation menu in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I just start up to be a web developer. Now I create a dynamic website for the first time. I don't know how to set `class="active"` to the navigation menu.
Here is my menu code:

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>patient/createpatient"><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Create Patient </a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
    <li>
       <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>patient/listpatient"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt fa-lg"> </i> List Patients </a> 
    </li>
<?php if( $usertype == "Admin"){?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/"><i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"> </i> List Users </a> 
    </li>`
```

Comment: @Craig I set the like below in `style.css` but it doesn't work

Comment: `li a.active{ 
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #53BEC5;
 }` @Craig

Comment: That will only work with my code. @saty has added the active class to the icon, not the link.

Comment: @Craig It works only two item. the last one it doesn't work. I try to test it for many times but still problem. `<a href="<?php echo site_url('user/'); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->uri_string() =="user/'') { echo 'active'; } ?>"><i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i> List Users</a>`

Comment: Remove the trailing slash on "user/" and see if that helps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `$this->uri->segment();`

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>patient/createpatient" <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="menu_name"){echo 'class="active"';}?> ><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Create Patient </a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
    <li>
       <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>patient/listpatient" <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="menu_name"){echo 'class="active"';}?> ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt fa-lg"> </i> List Patients </a> 
    </li>
<?php if( $usertype == "Admin"){?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/" <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="menu_name"){echo 'class="active"';}?> ><i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"> </i> List Users </a> 
    </li>
```

Comment: Sorry what is menu_name? what do you refer?

Comment: Consider `$this->uri->segment(1)` returns `createpatient` , then `"menu-name"` should be `"createpatient"`.. I wrote menu-name just for example. you should replace each with respective menu-names

Comment: for more simple `<?= uri_string() == 'profile' ? 'active':'' ?>`

Answer (score 12):

I do this on most projects. How I achieve this is like this;

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('patient/listpatient'); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'patient/listpatient') { echo 'active'; } ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt fa-lg"></i> List Patients</a>
```

It's matching the current uri string, with the links href. If it matches, it add's an active class to the link.

Hope this helps.

**I have also used site_url over base_url**

Comment: do I need to write code css to apply for the `class active`?

Comment: Yes. Without the CSS it'll look exactly the same. .active { font-weight: bold; }

Answer (score 4):

Try this one. I think no need of javascript or jquery.

If you are using codeigniter then you can use URI Class.
Get the menu from url using

```
$this->uri->segment();
```

and apply to you code like below

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>patient/listpatient"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt fa-lg <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="memu_name"){echo "active";}?>"> </i> List Patients </a> 

</li>
```

Comment: Using uri_segment() means his first 2 links will be active, as they both have "patient" at the first segment.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Codeigniter URI Class `$this->uri->segment();`

Please look at my code:

```
<li class="<?=($this->uri->segment(1)==='technology')?'active':''?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url('technology')?>">Tech</a></li>
```

Please note....

```
class="<?=($this->uri->segment(1)==='technology')?'active':''?>"
```

Also you can use URI Class `$this->uri->uri_string()`

Here is my active class for *home page(index)*

```
<li class="<?=($this->uri->uri_string()=== '')?'active':''?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url('')?>">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?=site_url('contact')?>" <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="contact") {echo 'class="active nav__item-link"';}?> class="nav__item-link">Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).