# how to dynamically set the active class in bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap nav bar with codeigniter as backend.

Now In my application i want to change the < li> class to active dynamically for each page.

So i can known i am on which page currently.

Below is my code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/company');?>">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/user');?>">Users Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/key');?>">Key Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/activation');?>">Activated Devices</a></li>

  </ul>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Comment: hi you need to review [How can I set class=“active” to navigation menu in codeignitor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367084/how-can-i-set-class-active-to-navigation-menu-in-codeignitor)

Comment: @ShaileshSingh i want to set active to the page i am currently on!! I have a main layout whre i have defined the site style

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this javascript to add active class based on current url please try it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
        $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
             return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works like charm.. Thanks a ton

Comment: I don't seem to need $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');, only the statement under it. Any explanation of what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use this replacing your `<a>` tags. This will match the current uri string, with the links `href` attribute. If it matches, it add's an `active` class to the link. You can style the `.active` using you

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/company'); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'admin/company') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Company</a>
```

So the entire code will be.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'admin/dashboard') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/company'); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'admin/company') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/user'); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'admin/user') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Users Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/key'); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'admin/key') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Key Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/activation'); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'admin/activation') { echo 'active'; } ?>">Activated Devices</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Comment: didnt understand how will this?

Answer (score 1):

Your pages should know which menu should be set as active.

Try adding an id to your `<li>` and add a javascript code to your pages to set the active menu based on the ID.
Example:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li id="menu-dashboard" class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li id="menu-company"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/company');?>">Company</a></li>
        <li id="menu-user"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/user');?>">Users Management</a></li>
        <li id="menu-key-management"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/key');?>">Key Management</a></li>
        <li id="menu-activation"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/activation');?>">Activated Devices</a></li>
  </ul>

<script>
var menuid = "menu-dashboard";
$(function() {
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(menuid).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Pages:
Add the following javascript lines to your pages

- Company page

  menuid = "#menu-company";
- User page

  menuid = "#menu-user";

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery` in the accepted answer do not know the difference if the visitor is coming from `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/index.php` and would not activate the "home" menu-item. This is my fix for that.

HTML This is a snippet from my menu:

```
<div class='navbar'>
    <a href='index.php'><div class='nav-icon icon-home'></div>Hem</a>
    <a href='calender.php'><div class='nav-icon icon-calender'></div>Kalender</a>
    <a href='exchange.php#utbyte'><div class='nav-icon icon-byte'></div>Byten</a>
</div>
```

This is a function I've added to my database controller class to find out what protocol the visitor use:

```
public static function adr_protocol()
{
    $str = 'http://';
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && 'on' === $_SERVER['HTTPS']) $str = 'https://';
    return $str;
}
```

jQuery:

```
;var ix = '<?php echo DBController::adr_protocol()."{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/"; ?>';
var url = (window.location==ix)?window.location+'index.php':window.location;
$('div.navbar a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
$('div.navbar a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using jQuery or JavaScript.

jQuery example:

```
$('.nav li').click(function(){
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: this works partially when i click it changes the active to that link but when i am redirected to that page it again become the dashboard to active