# Dynamically changing "active" class or adding navbar to each page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find out how to dynamically change the class="active" on my bootstrap navbar (html code below). I wanted to know if it would then be better to re-type all the `<nav>...</nav>` code in every page, and type class="active" on every `<li>` item separately, or create a separate navbar.html file and include it in top of every file, and then add a script or PHP code to change it? (which I can't find out how to).

And in general, which of the two approaches is better?

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427641/how-to-dynamically-set-the-active-class-in-bootstrap-navbar?rq=1

Comment: That's not a duplicate, there are way too many threads in Stack Exchange on how to do that, some PHP and some JS, and none of them work for my code.
I also asked which is better: to copy the nav bar to every page, or separate, which does not appear on other threads

Comment: Then it's asking for opinions and that definitely **off-topic**

Comment: I'm not asking for opinions only, I have a specific problem with the above html, and yes, I already saw the script above, and it didn't work. I also asked how to place it- in every page or in a separate page for that to work, that's related to this specific question, not off-topic

Comment: The only problem is that it's by accident on jquery instead of twitter bootstrap

Comment: *"which of the two approaches is better?"* is definitely asking for opinions,

Comment: That was just a small addition at the end, if you want I can remove that (I don't see what's the problem though, because I believe those who can answer the rest won't have any problem to answer that as well) - But, the main questions were: how to do that for my code, and whether to do that on separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Changing class dynamically

```
    $('.navbar-nav li').click( function () {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

this one works for me in my jsp page using jQuery, made changes considering your code

you may try this

Comment: That didn't work, but I think there's a problem with what I do:
I create a navbar.php file, copy all the nav content, then I save.
On every page (Home, Contact, etc), I include the first line below body the navbar.php. Also, I created a current.js file with the code above, and I put on each page the link to think script. Still not working

Comment: Edit: That didn't work even when I copy the code above in each page with script tags

Comment: write alert in this function and check it is executing or not

Answer (score 0):

```
PageOne.html
<body>
 <header id="Include">
 </header>
 <section class="sectionOne">
    <h1>This is Page one</h1>
 </section> 
</body>
```

---

```
PageTwo.html
<body>
 <header id="Include">
 </header>
 <section class="sectionOne">
    <h1>This is Page two</h1>
 </section> 
</body>
```

---

```
Header.html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">page one</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagetwo.html">page two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

---

```
App.js
  $('#Include').load('header.html', function(){
      var Murl = location.pathname;
//Murl gets the pathname from addressbar
      var ActiveUrl = Murl.slice(1, Murl.length);
      $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
//ThisURL gets all the href from navbar
      var ThisURL = $('.navbar-nav li a').attr('href');
      if(ThisURL = ActiveUrl){
          $('.navbar-nav li a[href="'+ ThisURL +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
      }
  });
```

Hope this may solve your problem. I have used only jquery.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to include it with script or php code. according the the url suffix you can write script to change the active of the li

Comment: The problem is I've read all Stack Exchange threads about it, and some post with PHP and some with JS/JQuery, but they do not work. Maybe you can help for the specific one? Ty