# How to make a Bootstrap 5 navbar dynamically change active class

Tags: html, class, dynamic

I have a navbar.php include file which i would like to make dynamic depending which url i am on. I am working on a php file with the latest version of bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="topheader">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about-us">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/our-work">Our Work</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I guess this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427641/how-to-dynamically-set-the-active-class-in-bootstrap-navbar